# How to increment a variable in a table and access it?

Tags: lua

I have a table defined like:

```
local counter = {    
deleted = 0,    
moved = 0,    
sumOfFileSize = 0,    
}
```

I have tried the following to increment or get the values, but it doesn't work:

increment: `counter.deleted = counter.deleted + 1`

get: `counter.deleted`

How can I successfully modify or read these values?

Comment: That code works just fine. See [here](https://eval.in/205361). Are you perhaps trying that in the interpreter(REPL)? That doesn't preserve locals between lines. Drop `local` from the table and it should work.

Comment: What exactly is the symptom of code not working?

Comment: e.g. counter.deleted is always 0.

Comment: I removed     local    , but nothing changed. My extension has just one file. And the table isn't declared in a function or another block.

Answer (score 0):

if youre using in some functions you need to declare whitout local, and meaby you can declare it in the top of the file with

```
counter={deleted = 0,
 moved = 0,
 sumOfFileSize = 0}
```

for access in all the functions you want.

The problem is from another place because i try this in console and here its the result, so the problem isnt lua

```
counter = {
 deleted = 0,
 moved = 0,
 sumOfFileSize = 0,
 }
 print(counter)
table: 0x7fb1e2e005d0
 counter.deleted = counter.deleted + 1

 print(counter.deleted)
1
 counter.deleted = counter.deleted + 1
 print(counter.deleted)
2
 counter.deleted = counter.deleted + 1
 print(counter.deleted)
3
```